# CSS won't update in the browser

Tags: css, browser-cache

So I'm having this really weird bug with my new server where the CSS won't update in the browser. Refreshing and clearing the cache doesn't work. I then opened up FileZilla to see if the updated CSS file is actually being uploaded to server using FTP, which it is, and then when I drag a copy of the css file to my desktop, the css file magically updates. The PHP file updates just fine.

Here's how I include the css: `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/stylesheet.css">`

I have no idea what is happening and how to fix this so any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can you show some information such as the browser you're using, your server configuration, the HTML, etc.?

Comment: somehow you are probably calling your css sheet  from your computer. That's why you can see it working once you copy it locally. To be sure if this is the reason open your web in another computer, tablet, phone when you think it's working properly

Comment: Can you post the code that shows how you include the CSS?

Comment: if you load the URL to your CSS file directly in the browser, e.g `http://yourdomain.com/css/stylesheet.css` does it show the correct (new) content?

Comment: @scunliffe Not like that no. When I do it like this with the time() function like suggested in another comment it does work though: `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://yourdomain.com/css/stylesheet.css?d=<?php echo time(); ?>">`

Answer (score 9):

You could have any number of issues, but I'd like to point out a cool tip when using Chrome.

On your page, ***with the developer tools open*** if you press and hold the reload button you get a great option to clear the cache and hard reload!

[image]

This is very handy to make sure you have the "freshest" copy while developing.

**Update:**
As for your scenario (after reading updates) it sounds like an HTTP header issue with your CSS file.

Check what HTTP headers are being sent with your CSS file response.  If you are not specifying a cache header it will likely try to cache for you.  Set an expires header (in the past) when in development, but far in the future when in production.  In the *Network* tab of your developer tools (most browsers) you should be able to see these headers, or you can use a too like [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/download/fiddler) that will let you deeply inspect your network traffic.

Alternatively if you can't easily tweak the HTTP Headers, then set a far expires header, **but** ensure the path to the file changes whenever you make a code change. Options include:

- adding a time() stamp (always changes (yeah!) but doesn't cache (boo))
- add the version control # to the file URL (works great, but you need to manage the updates properly within your tooling)
- something fancier that creates a generated "fake" path to the file that auto changes on any modification to the file... but also loads the URL as expected, and sets the cache to "forever" (max 365 days according to the HTTP specs)

Comment: Very handy tip that I didn't know about, but it doesn't fix the problem.

Comment: Understood... can you provide a code sample? e.g. if you have `<link href="some/file.css">` you may have issues without specifying the type as `type="text/css"`?... we really need the code sample to help you out.

Comment: Yeah I edited my main post with how I include my css. I'm doing it the same way I've always been doing it. For some reason it just seems buggy on this new server.

Comment: Thank you!
I've been stuck with a CSS-file who wouldn't update forever. Normally I could just go into the debugger, and reload the page with it open. If that didn't work, I'd look up the relevant file in sources, and then update. This time none of those worked. I even tried to restart my computer and everything. This tip was the only thing that worked. I've been doing web development for three years, and this is the only time I've had such a hard time getting the CSS to load...

Answer (score 1):

You may try queries to force the browser to load fresh CSS when it loads. To do this

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css-file-name.css?v=1.1">
```

If you are comfortable with php you may try below code to force the browser to load most updated CSS to load. To do this

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://example.com/style.css?d=<?php echo time(); ?>" />
```

This will ensure browsers always load fresh CSS with last modified time stamp.

Hope this help you.

Comment: The PHP method works! Do you have any idea why this is happening though and how to fix it? It doesn't seem optimal to have to do this, but at least it'll work until I find a fix.

Comment: It happens because browser cache the links and files temporarily and reuse them to speed up page load time. It is normal behavior of browsers. Further, there is no issue with above technique to load the fresh copy. Once the development is done and website is up on the server, we should leverage browser caching to speed up the load time.