# How can I backup and load my local storage in chrome?

Tags: javascript, html, cookies, local-storage, local

How can I backup and load my local storage in chrome?

I'm playing some HTML5 games which could only run in chrome, they depend on local storage to save data, no account or save code.

But I also need to use chrome for my js / ts program to debug and run, my program also have run in chrome. sometimes js does not synchronized with browser, so I need to clear cache(Chrome -> clear browser data, or cmd + shift + delete)
https://stackoverflow.com/a/32572490/18248235

but then I will lose my game data then. And also sometimes I want to export data into another computer, I need to backup my local storage too.

Can I backup and load my data manually?

Comment: I'm afraid your question is unclear: how are you clearing the cache? Local storage depends on the [origin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Origin), so if you run `localStorage.clear()` on your program's page it will clear only that page data.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado I used clear browser data in chrome, I edited my question

Comment: So, in that case, stop clearing all Chrome's cache, just open the dev tools and do `localStorage.clear()` when needed.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado Yes, but are there some better way that I can backup or export local storage and reload it? It will be safer and easier to transfer data

Answer (score 0):

Multiple ways to do this. The pretty straight forward answer would be to figure out which key is your game data, then in your console in devtools `console.log(localStorage.getItem(<yourKey>))` then copy the string that results and paste it into a local file. You can then later upload the data again with `localStorage.setItem(<yourkey>, <data>)`

Edit: added second parameter needed for setItem

I also found this after researching a little if you would like to backup all localstorage: [save restore local storage to a local file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24263682/save-restore-local-storage-to-a-local-file)